# How would I print out certain values of an Array with booleans in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

I made a program that prints out manipulated arrays, I would like to reprint all values in the pass[i] array that has a length equal to 7 but Java seems to only reprint the entire set. I am guessing that I am doing something very wrong with my handling of booleans...

```
String[] pass = new String[cnt];
int[] range = new int[cnt];
int[] arr = new int[cnt];
boolean valid;

for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    pass[i] = afname[i] + asname[i];
    if (pass[i].length() == 7) {
        System.out.println(pass[i]);
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
        if ((7 - pass[i].length()) >= 3) {
            range[i] = (int) Math.pow(10, (7 - pass[i].length())) - 100;
            System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
        } else {
            if ((7 - pass[i].length()) == 2) {
                range[i] = 99;
                System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
            } else {
                range[i] = 9;
                System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

if(valid){
     for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++){
        System.out.println(pass[i]);
     }
  }
  else{System.out.println("Cannot print");}
```

Output without if(valid) statement...

```
jbeebee
span900
baroura
apentz9
swillia
ajenn99
```

Output with if(valid) statement...

```
jbeebee
span900
baroura
apentz9
swillia
ajenn99
Cannot print
```

Comment: `if(valid = true)` `=` is assignment operator which assigns `true` to `valid` which then is evaluated as `if(true)`, What you need is comparison operator `==`, or even better skip `==true` part since it is redundant and makes your code error-prone `if (valid)`.

Comment: I now stated, if(valid) but Java will still not print anything

Comment: @Pshemo where should I post these type of questions?

Comment: @tuxi If this was not the only problem then simply [edit] your code and your question will be on-topic.

Comment: @tuxi can you please post what is the error ? and what do you want from your java application ? That will be a great resource.

Comment: @tuxi I edited your code to correct `if(valid = true)`, but you should consider postint complete example which we could use to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: @tuxi are you sure one string is of length 7?

Comment: Yes, there are 3 strings in the array that have a length of 7

Comment: @tuxi You shouldn't update your code, as it is for future viewers unclear what your asking. Oh, and your last else statement is not correct.

Comment: @moffeltje oh okay, what would be the correct statement

Comment: You cannot add an `else` clause after an `for`-loop

Comment: @tuxi Please make sure that when you post/update your code it is code you actually used. Otherwise there is no point in even reading it since it can have very little to do with your real problem. I am writing this because you just added `else` to `for` loop which couldn't possibly compile.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you for that I see i have missed out a bracket, i have now copied and pasted the code so it does compile correctly. The output statements still remain the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `valid` will be `true` after loop only if **last** element of array has 7 symbols. However even if `valid` will be `true` after the loop you print entire array. But as I understand from your question you need to print only strings with 7 symbols.

One way is to create another array (or `List`) to store string with 7 symbols.

```
String[] pass = new String[cnt];
int[] range = new int[cnt];
int[] arr = new int[cnt];
List<String> valids = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    pass[i] = afname[i] + asname[i];
    if (pass[i].length() == 7) {
        System.out.println(pass[i]);
        valids.add(pass[i]);
    } else {
        if ((7 - pass[i].length()) >= 3) {
            range[i] = (int) Math.pow(10, (7 - pass[i].length())) - 100;
            System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
        } else {
            if ((7 - pass[i].length()) == 2) {
                range[i] = 99;
                System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
            } else {
                range[i] = 9;
                System.out.println(pass[i] + range[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

if(valids.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("No entries with length of 7");
} else {
    System.out.println("Entries with length of 7:");
    for(String s : valids){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Another is to create `boolean` array and mark its elements as `true` if corresponding element of `pass` has required length.

Also you can simply make another check of the length without `valid` variable.

```
for(String s : pass){
    if(s.length() == 7) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```